Implement logic in back-end using getServerSideProps
Good morning, my head hurts i've been smashing it against the wall for so long!
As the subject  says i need to move some logic from the client-side to the backend, so that the API url is not exposed on the front end.
It has been suggested to use getServerSideProps. I've read every article and tried every solution that seems available, but I still can't get it to work as expected. Please can I get some help?
//commsPage.tsx
createImportantMsg(email, reqDetails);


//createComms.ts
export const createImportantMsg = async (
  email: string,
  customerDetails: CustDetsRequest
): Promise<void> => {
  await makeAuthApiCall(
    {
      url: `${process.env.API_DOMAIN_URL}${process.env.COMM}?value1=1&value2=2&value3=3`,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        coms: {
          characteristic: [
            {
              name: "ian",
              value: "great",
            },
            {
              name: "keith",
              value: "good",
            },
            {
              name: "sally",
              value: "awesome",
            },
          ],
          content: "contents",
          receiver: {
            emailAddress: email,
            phoneNumber: customerDetails.number,
          },
          sender: {
            id: process.env.ID,
            name: process.env.NAME,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    ErrorImportanceTypes.IGNORED
  );
};

Thanks in advance.
